# unable to insert chense character mysql

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, chinese-locale

Hi I am trying to insert some Chinese characters in my sql database. For some character I am not getting any issues, but for the 2nd insert 2nd character I am getting error as shown below. Has anyone faced this kind of issue before. am I choosing wrong character set or collation?

Reference 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/faqs-cjk.html#faq-cjk-why-cjk-fail-searches

```
CREATE TABLE testing (test VARCHAR(500) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci);
INSERT INTO testing VALUES('薛');
INSERT INTO testing VALUES('薛萍'); -- ERROR - MySQL Database Error: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\xA6\x86\xB1\xE8\x90...' for column 'test' at row 1
select * from testing;
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [Unicode character inspector](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%E8%96%9B%F0%A6%86%B1%E8%90%8D) the UTF encoding for `薛萍` is:

```
薛 = E8 96 9B
 = F0 A6 86 B1
萍 = E8 90 8D
```

MySQL complaints about this:

```
\xF0\xA6\x86\xB1\xE8\x90
```

So everything is apparently correct, save for a little implementation detail about `utf8_unicode_ci` which, in MySQL, is an incomplete UTF-8 encoding that only accepts up to three byte characters. Thus  cannot be stored as `utf8_unicode_ci`.

You need to switch to some `utf8mb4_...` encoding.

Comment: still not working, have you tried 
drop table testing;
CREATE TABLE testing (test VARCHAR(500) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4);
INSERT INTO testing VALUES('薛萍');

Comment: Are you getting the same exact error message? Have you configured your database connection, in whatever client language or framework you use, for utf8mb4 instead of utf8?

Comment: No i havent changed anything at database level, i just changed the character set at table level as showed in my script.

Comment: No, you don't need to change anything at database level. Just configure whatever client language or framework you use for utf8mb4 instead of utf8. Are you connecting from the command line? Is it a Java program? Something else?

Comment: I am trying to execute using Toad for SQL Developer. Executing direct insert statements.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that software, sorry. In the official command-line client `CREATE TABLE testing (test VARCHAR(500) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4); INSERT INTO testing VALUES('薛萍');` runs flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to having the *column* set to utf8mb4, you must also tell MySQL that the *client* is speaking utf8mb4 (not just utf8).  For some clients, this is best done when making the connection, for some there is a secondary command, such as `SET NAMES utf8mb4` which should be performed right after connecting.

Debugging Q&A:  [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

That seems to be a rather unusual (or new?) Chinese character; even http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=f0a686b1 fails to show the graphic.